# Identifying sender from Control.InvokeOnClick()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I am writing a minesweeper app and I try to raise the click event recursively from click event if I open the tile which has 0 mines around it. I need to figure out if what will be the sender of the recursive call, using `InvokeOnClick()`.

```
picture1.Click += (sender,e) => {//some switch case
case 0: //when 0 mines are around
InvokeOnClick(picture2,e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/control.cs,852870e05b8c042d) reveals the answer. `InvokeOnClick` calls protected method `OnClick` of target control, which then invokes `Click` event with `this` (equal to target control) as `sender` meaning that the target control will be the `sender` parameter for its own `Click` event.

```
// snippet from Reference Source

protected void InvokeOnClick(Control toInvoke, EventArgs e) {
    if (toInvoke != null) {
        toInvoke.OnClick(e);
    }
}

// ...

protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
    Contract.Requires(e != null);
    EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Events[EventClick];
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

In your case `InvokeOnClick(picture2, e);` will invoke `picture2.Click` event with parameter `sender` set to `picture2`.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now!